# Local Host refused to connect

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, network-security

I have a web api project for which I enabled ssl from the properties and downloaded the certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authority.In this project I have a class that redirects http into https.I have a client who calls my http api using ngrok,this request is getting redirected to ssl port.I have pasted the certificate that I downloaded on my machine while enabling ssl,to the Trusted Root Certification Authority on the client's machine,but the client is not able to access the api,it says that the localhost refused to connect and shows the following errors:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. --->
>
> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:44343
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception exception)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   arat)

I called my first api using the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44343/");


HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://ccb7fe34.ngrok.io/api/Server").Result;

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
     {
           Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           res = result.Result;
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(res);
     }
     var des = (ForVersion)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res, typeof(ForVersion));
     string updated_version = des.version;
     string current_version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
     if (current_version != updated_version)
     {
          UpdateAvailable f = new UpdateAvailable();
          f.ShowDialog();
     }
 }
```

Comment: LocalHost on your computer is not the same as LocalHost on ClientMachine. Show some code, otherwise there is no way to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I have added the code above to call my first api,the application was working fine earlier but after implementing ssl on server side the application shows error.